# Relation beetween log-space reduction and polynomial time reduction

Tags: complexity-theory, space-complexity, polynomial-time

I read somewhere that given two languages $A$ and $B$, if $A \le_{\log} B$, then $A \le_P B$ (with $\le_{\log}$ the log-space reduction and $\le_P$ the polynomial time reduction), but I'm not sure about the proof.

Could someone help me with that please.

Answer (score 2):

Every terminating Turing machine running in logarithmic space terminates in polynomial time. This is because the number of configurations in a logarithmic space Turing machine is polynomial; a logspace Turing machine running longer than the number of configurations will necessarily repeat a configuration, and so will never terminate.

More generally, $\mathsf{SPACE}(f(n)) \subseteq \mathsf{TIME}(2^{O(f(n))})$ for similar reasons. This gives not only $\mathsf{L} \subseteq \mathsf{P}$ but also $\mathsf{PSPACE} \subseteq \mathsf{EXPTIME}$.